# How to change order of items in js object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out this problem for hours. I have javascript object which is an array of over 10 items. Each item has its own, unique key as it's required. The problem is that I'm trying to somehow shuffle items in object to render them in different order that they were previously. I tried with `Math.random()` function, but it doesn't solve the problem. Is it even possible to change order of items in object?

Comment: Please pose your question as a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so far it is not clear if you data looks like this ``[ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]`` or something else. Also not clear what your desired outcome data format is. Please specify both and any code you have tried.

Comment: Array has order not an object;

Answer (score 1):

You can Randomize Json objects using [Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) assuming you have a JSON object like this

```
let jsonObj = [
  {a : 1},
  {a : 2},
  {a : 3}
]


function shuffleArray(jsonObj) {
    for (var i = jsonObj.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = jsonObj[i];
        jsonObj[i] = jsonObj[j];
        jsonObj[j] = temp;
    }
    console.log(jsonObj);
}
```

You can see the coding running below.
[image: Below you can see the results]

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately. ```console.log``` returns repeated numbers, for example 4 times 0 or 2 times 1. I also checked in ```console.log``` ```shuffleArray and it returns ```undefined``` items

Comment: you have to call the function with jsonobj like this to see the result. shuffleArray(jsonObj).. Edited my Answer showing it working.!

Comment: okay, I will try

Comment: okay, it's working perfect. Thanks so much